# Regex to parses string containing escape character for URL

Tags: java, regex

I have sample Url that I am trying to read from a file 
I have to parse URL which contains an escape character before : 
eg  https://www.sample.co.in:8080? 
or http://www.sample.co.in

Sadly the regex I have written

```
Regex = \w*\\:.*
```

helps to parse the second example. Wherever I get a : that should have a preffix of '\'. If I have a string like this http:\www.google.com It should not pass. 
I am trying to extract text from a log file.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using the `URI` class?

Comment: i dont understand 2 things, 1) the question 2) what the upvote is for?

Comment: what is your ultimate motive just creating a valid url or parsing the url and getting attributes?

Comment: I need to read certain data from a log file, this I think cant be done with the URI class.

Comment: Apache commons also has an URLValidator, which is quite nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking thru various references I managed to build the regex I was looking for.

```
String regex = "(query=.*?(?<!\\\\):)+.*?";
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(regex);
String notvalue = "query=https\\://www.localhost.com\\:80";
String passvalue = "query=https://www.localhost.com\\:80";
```

Thanks Everyone. :)
This returns true when we give an incorrect URL which should not be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to validate the url then there are already many good answer one of them says

You can try like this for url validation

```
String lRegex = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
```

On the other hand if you want to get the properties from the url try like this

```
URL aURL = new URL("https:/www.sample.co.in:8080");
System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol());
System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority());
System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost());
System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort());
```